# golang global struct initialization

Tags: go, struct, initialization, global

I want to declare a global struct variable which belongs to a certain package and initialize it.

I have a following directory structure:

```
main
├── symbol
|   ├── symbol.go
|   └── Comma.go
├── main.go
└── go.mod
```

**symbol.go**:

```go
package symbol

type Symbol struct{
    Name string
    Format string
}
```

**Comma.go**:

```go
package symbol

var Comma = Symbol{}

Comma.Name = "Comma"
Comma.Format = ","
```

**main.go**:

```go
package main
import "fmt"
import "github.com/.../symbol"

func main() {
    s := symbol.Comma
    fmt.Println(s.Name)
}
```

When I run this, it says: 
`syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaration statements are the only statement type allowed at package-level.  The statements

```
Comma.Name = "Comma"
Comma.Format = ","
```

are assignment statements. Assigments are not declarations.

There are two ways to fix the problem.  The first and preferred way is to initialize the value in the variable declaration using a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

```
 var Comma = Symbol{Name: "Comma", Format: ","}
```

The second way is to move the assignment statements to an `init` function:

```
func init() {
    Comma.Name = "Comma"
    Comma.Format = ","
}
```

`init` functions are automatically executed when the package is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Use a composite literal:

```
var Comma = Symbol{Name: "Comma", Format: ","}
```

[The Go Programming Language Specification: Composite literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals)